# Download files in android

Tags: android, download

I am trying to write an application that downloads files in the background. The code crashes when it tries to reenter doInBackground(). This happens when doing is set to false before returning. Code follows -

```
public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private boolean doing;
    private Activity activity;
    private Intent intent;
    private File beta;
    private File alpha;

    public DownloadFile(Activity act, Intent intent) {
        this.activity = act;
        this.intent = intent;
        doing = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        int fileCount = 0;
        if (!download(sUrl[0] + "list.txt",
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/alpha/list.txt")){
            setDoing(false);
            return "Download failed";//list.txt could not be downloaded. return error message.
        }
        fileCount++;

        beta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/beta/");
        File betalist = new File(beta + "/list.txt");

        alpha = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/alpha/");
        File alphalist = new File(alpha + "/list.txt");

        //verify that the file is changed.
        if (alphalist.lastModified() == betalist.lastModified()// these two are
                                                                // never equal.
                || alphalist.length() == betalist.length()) { // better to check
                                                                // the length of
                                                                // the files.
            setDoing(false);
            return "Nothing to download.";
        }



        try {
            FileReader inAlpha = new FileReader(alphalist);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inAlpha);
            String s;

            // read the name of each file in a loop
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
//              if(fileExistsInBeta(s)){
//                  copyFromBetaToAlpha(s);
//                  continue;
//              }
                // download the file. 
                //Url will truncate the trailing / so keep if statement as is.
                if (!download(sUrl[0] + s,
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/alpha/"
                                + s)){
                    setDoing(false);
                    return "Failed at " + s;// the given file could not be downloaded. return error.
                }
                fileCount++;
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Pankaj", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Pankaj", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Pankaj", e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.d("Pankaj", "Download Done");

        activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        activity.finish();

        Log.d("Pankaj", "MainActivity Killed");
        // rename alpha to beta

        deleteSubFolders(beta.toString());
        beta.delete();
        alpha.renameTo(beta);
        if (!alpha.exists()) {
            alpha.mkdir();
        }
        File upper = new File(alpha + "/upper/");
        if (!upper.exists())
            upper.mkdirs();
        File lower = new File(alpha + "/lower/");
        if (!lower.exists())
            lower.mkdirs();

//      ConfLoader.getInstance().reload();//to refresh the settings
        // restart the activity
        activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        Log.d("Pankaj", "MainActivity restarted");

        // now reset done status so we can start again.
        setDoing(false);
        return "Download finished.";// return the status for onPostExecute.
    }

    private void copyFromBetaToAlpha(String fileName) {
        File beta=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/beta/"+fileName);
        File alpha=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/alpha/"+fileName);
        try {
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(beta);
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(alpha);
            byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while((len=fis.read(buf))>0){
                fos.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    public boolean download(String url, String file) {
        boolean successful = true;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            int filelen = conn.getContentLength();
            File f = new File(file);

            // skip download if lengths are same
            // because the file has been downed fully.
            if (f.exists() && filelen == f.length()) {
                return successful;
            }

            InputStream is = u.openStream();
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            while ((length = dis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, length);

            }
            fos.close();
            buffer = null;
            dis.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "malformed url error", mue);
            successful = false;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "io error", ioe);
            successful = false;
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "security error", se);
            successful = false;
        }
        return successful;
    }

    private void deleteSubFolders(String uri) {
        File currentFolder = new File(uri);
        File files[] = currentFolder.listFiles();

        if (files == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                deleteSubFolders(f.toString());
            }
            // no else, or you'll never get rid of this folder!
            f.delete();
        }
    }

    public static int getFilesCount(File file) {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        int count = 0;
        for (File f : files)
            if (f.isDirectory())
                count += getFilesCount(f);
            else
                count++;

        return count;
    }

    public boolean isDoing() {
        return doing;
    }

    /**
     * @param doing
     */
    public void setDoing(boolean doing) {
        this.doing = doing;
    }

    private boolean fileExistsInBeta(final String fileName){
        boolean exists=false;
        File beta=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/beta/"+fileName);
        if(beta.exists()){
            String[] ext=beta.getName().split(".");
            String extName=ext[ext.length-1];
            exists=(extName!="txt" && extName!="tmr" && extName!="conf");
        }
        return exists;
    }
```

in the main activity -

```
public void run() {
        if (!downloadFile.isDoing()) {
            downloadFile.execute(ConfLoader.getInstance().getListUrl());
            downloadFile.setDoing(true);
        }
        // change the delay so that it covers the time for download and
        // doesn't overlap causing multiple downloads jamming the bandwidth.

        h.postDelayed(this, 1000);//check after 60 sec.

    }
```

in the onCreate() -

```
downloadFile = new DownloadFile(this, getIntent());
h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The logcat error is Cannot execute task the task is already running.
Cannot execute task: Task has already been executed(A task can only be executed once).
EDIT:
Is it possible that the error is because I am trying to execute the asynchtask again in run(). Perhaps AsynchTask does not allow re-entry.

Comment: put your logcat here..

Comment: post error you got in logcat while app crash..

Comment: it might be bcoz you are trying to start the activity again from inside the doInBackground(), by calling this statement activity.startActivity(intent); By starting the activity again the AsyncTask is called again before it has finished executing. Thats why the error "Cannot execute task the task is already running".

Comment: adding downloadFile=new DownloadFile(this, getIntent()); to run() appears to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this
1. First create a dialogue

```
   @Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

1. The download async task

   ```
    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();

   showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
      }

       @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
   int count;
   File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();               
    //
   File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath()+"/Downl");
   if(dir.exists()==false) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
   File file = new File(dir, url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1)); //name of file
       try {

               URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
               URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
               conexion.connect();

               int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
               Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

               InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
               OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

               byte data[] = new byte[1024];

               long total = 0;

               while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) 
                   {
                       total += count;
                       publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                       output.write(data, 0, count);
                   }

               output.flush();
               output.close();
               input.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {}
       return null;

          }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
   dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
   Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this,"Successfully downloaded in phone memory.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
     }
   ```
2. Call the async new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url); //pass ur url